# Class that conforms to a protocol - compile time check

Tags: ios, objective-c, protocols

Is this valid syntax?

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) Class<SomeProtocol> myClass;
```

`SomeProtocol` is defined as:

```
@protocol SomeProtocol <NSObject>

@required
+ (BOOL)isAllowed;

@end
```

I want to enforce compile-time check such that the compiler complains when a class (`UIViewController` for example) that does not implement the required `isAllowed` method is used for the `myClass` property.

P.S. I get no compiler warnings or errors when I pass in a class that does not conform to the SomeProtocol protocol.

Comment: `@property (nonatomic, strong) id<SomeProtocol> myClass;` This is valid & used often

Comment: The question was more about Class<SomeProtocol> and not id<SomeProtocol>.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's syntactically valid, but as you have discovered, it will only check what messages you send the object, not warn you if a nonconforming class is passed in. The reason is that the static type of all classes is just `Class`, which is a dynamic type† — just like you can assign an `id` to a variable of any object type, you can assign a `Class` to any `Class` variable.

† Note: Just to be clear, this is not a technical use of the term "dynamic type." I don't know if there's a normal phrase for what `id` and `Class` are. I figure it should be pretty clear in context, but I'm using it to refer to the fact that it tells the compiler you do not want to declare a static type for the object, so the typing is dynamic like in Ruby or Python.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to enforce such a compile time check?

Comment: @pshah: I don't believe so. The core issue is that any method or function returning a class will return type `Class`, which the typechecker considers compatible with any other `Class`. It's the same deal with methods returning `id` — you can't enforce static type constraints on them, because `id` or `Class` means "actual type not known until runtime."